# What is the issue with this code, to match Junit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

Code needs to match test class (JUnit)
errors include: EstateAgency test, RemoveInvalidProperty test

All other tests past thus far, 
Thank you in advance!! :D

Any help will be appreciated, will be posting question 2 and 3 later on, look out for it!!

public class PropertyManagement {

```
private Agency estateAgency;
private List<House> properties = new ArrayList<House>();

public PropertyManagement(Agency estateAgency) {
    this.estateAgency = estateAgency;

}

public void addProperty(House property) {
    this.properties.add(property);
}

public void addTenant(House property, Room room, Tenant tenant) {
    property.occupyRoom(room, tenant);

}

public String displayProperties() {
    StringBuffer propertyList = new StringBuffer();
    for (House property : properties) {
        propertyList.append(property);
        propertyList.append("\n");

    }
    return propertyList.toString();

}

public Agency getEstateAgency() {
    return estateAgency;

}

public void removeProperty(House property) {
    properties.remove(property);
}
```

}

TEST CLASS
public class PropertyManagementTest {

```
@Test
public void testAddProperty() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);
    House house = new House(1, "Percy Road", "Guildford", "GU2 7XH", 2);

    pm.addProperty(house);

    assertEquals("1 Percy Road, Guildford GU2 7XH (2 bedroom house :2 available)\n", pm.displayProperties());

}

@Test
public void testAddTenant() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);

    House house1 = new House(1, "Percy Road", "Guildford", "GU2 7XH", 2);
    House house2 = new House(1, "The Chase", "Guildford", "GU2 7UB", 5);

    Room room1 = new Room(900);
    Room room2 = new Room(1000);

    Tenant tenant1 = new Tenant("Alice", "Wonderland", 18, TenantType.STUDENT);
    Tenant tenant2 = new Tenant("Stella", "Kazamia", 50, TenantType.PROFESSIONAL);

    pm.addProperty(house1);
    pm.addProperty(house2);

    pm.addTenant(house1, room1, tenant1);

    assertEquals(
            "1 Percy Road, Guildford GU2 7XH (2 bedroom house :1 available)\n"
                    + "1 The Chase, Guildford GU2 7UB (5 bedroom house :5 available)\n" + "",
            pm.displayProperties());
}

@Test
public void testDisplayHouses() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);

    House house1 = new House(1, "Percy Road", "Guildford", "GU2 7XH", 2);
    House house2 = new House(1, "The Chase", "Guildford", "GU2 7UB", 5);

    Room room1 = new Room(900);
    Room room2 = new Room(1000);

    Tenant tenant1 = new Tenant("Alice", "Wonderland", 18, TenantType.STUDENT);
    Tenant tenant2 = new Tenant("Stella", "Kazamia", 50, TenantType.PROFESSIONAL);

    pm.addProperty(house1);
    pm.addProperty(house2);

    pm.addTenant(house1, room1, tenant1);
    pm.addTenant(house2, room2, tenant2);

    assertEquals("1 Percy Road, Guildford GU2 7XH (2 bedroom house :1 available)\n"
            + "1 The Chase, Guildford GU2 7UB (5 bedroom house :4 available)\n", pm.displayProperties());
}

@Test
public void testGetEstateAgency() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);

    assertEquals("Agency: Simple Lettings, Phone Number: 01234 567890", pm.getEstateAgency());
}

@Test
public void testPropertyManagement() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);

    assertEquals("", pm.displayProperties());
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testRemoveInvalidProperty() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);

    House house1 = new House(1, "Percy Road", "Guildford", "GU2 7XH", 2);

    pm.removeProperty(house1);
}

@Test
public void testRemoveProperty() {
    Agency estate = new Agency("Simple Lettings", "01234 567890");
    PropertyManagement pm = new PropertyManagement(estate);

    House house1 = new House(1, "Percy Road", "Guildford", "GU2 7XH", 2);
    House house2 = new House(1, "The Chase", "Guildford", "GU2 7UB", 5);

    Room room1 = new Room(900);

    Tenant tenant1 = new Tenant("Alice", "Wonderland", 18, TenantType.STUDENT);

    pm.addProperty(house1);
    pm.addProperty(house2);

    pm.addTenant(house1, room1, tenant1);

    pm.removeProperty(house2);

    assertEquals("1 Percy Road, Guildford GU2 7XH (2 bedroom house :1 available)\n", pm.displayProperties());
}
```

}

Comment: Add more information about your code to your post and properly format your code please

Comment: @KevinHernandez Im quite new to java, not sure exactly what you mean by formatting? Thanks

Comment: Not java formatting, the code you posted onto the question needs to be formatted correctly, highlight it with your cursor and press `ctrl + k`

Comment: Two questions, 1. is this production code? and 2. how can people run these tests without code? Classes Room, Tenant, Propertymanagement etc. are missing.